# When can we say that $T\in B(H)$ is $YS$ for some fixed $S$ in $B(H)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T,S\in B(H)$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space. 
Suppose that for all $x\in H$, $\|Tx\|\leq \|Sx\|$. 
Could we then say that $T=YS$ for some $Y\in B(H)$? Would it help if $S$ were a contraction or positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lVert Tx\rVert \leqslant \lVert Sx\rVert$ for all $x\in H$ implies $\ker S \subset \ker T$, the map

$$W\colon \mathcal{R}(S) \to \mathcal{R}(T);\quad Sx \mapsto Tx$$

is well-defined (the value $Tx$ does not depend on the chosen $x\in S^{-1}(\{y\})$ for $y\in \mathcal{R}(S)$), and continuous. We can extend it by continuity to $\widetilde{W} \colon\overline{\mathcal{R}(S)}\to H$, and compose it with the orthogonal projection $P\colon H \to \overline{\mathcal{R}(S)}$ to obtain

$$T = \underbrace{\widetilde{W}\circ P}_Y \circ S.$$

No special properties of $S$ are required.